# error C2297: '*' : illegal, right operand has type 'BYTE *'

Tags: c++, c, windows, assembly, hook

Why is giving this error on this line?

```
*(BYTE*)(dwAddr + 5) = 0xC3;
```

Main.cpp (34): error C2297: '*': illegal, right operand has type 'BYTE *'

```
void PushRetHook(DWORD dwAddr, LPVOID dwNew, int size)
{
    DWORD OldProt;
    VirtualProtect((void*)dwAddr, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OldProt);
    memset((void*)(dwAddr), 0x90, size);
    *(BYTE*)dwAddr = 0x68;
    *(DWORD*)(dwAddr + 1) = (DWORD)dwNew
    *(BYTE*)(dwAddr + 5) = 0xC3;
    VirtualProtect((void*)(dwAddr), size, OldProt, &OldProt);
}
```

Comment: Writing multi language source files (C and C++) is hard work. I suggest you write only one language.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a semicolon

```
    *(DWORD*)(dwAddr + 1) = (DWORD)dwNew // <== missing semicolon
    *(BYTE*)(dwAddr + 5) = 0xC3;
```